# Transition of color affecting top‽

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm using Firefox 52.9.0.

I'm trying to add a [skip navigation link](https://webaim.org/techniques/skipnav/) to a page. Currently, page looks like this:

```css
/* Accessibility */
  /* Hide the skip to main content link unless it has focus */
body > a:first-child {
  background: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: -1em;
  transition: top 2s ease-out;
}
body > a::first-child:not(:focus) {
}
body > a:first-child:focus {
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<a href="#lorem">skip to main content</a>
<main id="lorem">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum... can't remember the rest, sorry.</p>
  <p>This CSS is mostly fine.</p>
</main>
```

(Click on the page and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to see the effect.)

This looks fine, except the descender and underline are visible. In order to deal with this, I told the browser to change the text colour to `transparent` when it didn't have focus:

```css
/* Accessibility */
  /* Hide the skip to main content link unless it has focus */
body > a:first-child {
  background: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: -1em;
  transition: top 2s ease-out;
  transition: color 2s ease-out;
}
body > a:first-child:not(:focus) {
  color: darkgoldenrod;
}
body > a:first-child:focus {
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 0.1s ease-in;
  transition: color 0.1s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="#lorem">skip to main content</a>
<main id="lorem">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum... can't remember the rest, sorry.</p>
  <p>This CSS behaves strangely.</p>
</main>
```

(`transparent` is substituted for `darkgoldenrod` so it's easier to see the effect.)

The `color` transition works, but for some reason it's stopped the `top` transition from working!

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: The original problem was caused by the fact that you needed to start at `-1lh`, not `-1em`. Unfortunately, it's only 2018 and the `lh` unit doesn't exist yet. Oh well. Hey look, an interrobang.

Comment: @MrLister I need IE11 to fail-usable, so I have to use old stuff anyway. Out of interest, would `lh` deal correctly with Zalgo text? (That's masses of combining diacriticals, if you didn't know.) I suspect not, since Zalgo overlaps lines below.

Comment: `lh` is (or, will be) simply the computed size of the line height, so, no.

Comment: @MrLister Ok, so I'll still need the `color` thing. Could I use `top: -1em; top: -1lh;` to have correct behaviour when it's supported?

Comment: `top:-1.2em; top:-1lh;` should be better, since the default line height is about 1.2em.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second `transition` declaration erases, not adds to, the first one. This is the cascade at work.

You can't declare separate transitions additively using multiple `transition` declarations; you will need to group them into a single declaration like so:

```css
body > a:first-child:focus {
  top: 0px;
  transition: top 0.1s ease-in, color 0.1s linear;
}
```

Comment: CSS properties _can only be defined once_. No exceptions. (Remember that next time, me!)